# How to calculate mean value of one Variable conditional on another variable's quantile splits?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Here is the question:

1. Conditional on Time splits one variable(X) into deciles, i.e 10 quantile
2. Calculate arbitrary mean of another Variable(Y) condition on X's quantile and Time

Here is the fake data:

```
    library(data.table)
    set.seed(1)
    dat = as.data.table(data.frame(X = round(abs(rnorm(100))*100,2),
    Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-04-01"),"month"),25),
    Y = round(rnorm(100),2)))
```

Here is the quantile splits:

```
    dat[, ':=' (Quantile  = dplyr::ntile(X,10)),by = Time][]
```

The Grouped value condition on both Time and Quantile seems quite clear

```
    dat[,`:=` (MeanY = mean(Y)),by = c("Time","Quantile")]
```

Or

```
    dat[, MeanY = mean(Y) ,by = c("Time","Quantile")]
```

The question is How can I get arbitrary mean Y, condition on all X's top, such as 10,9,8, or bottom 1,2,3 quantile

Any help great Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want here. If you wanted the mean just for quantiles 8 through 10, you could do:

```
dat[Quantile %in% 8:10, list(MeanY = mean(Y)), by = Time]
#          Time      MeanY
# 1: 2016-01-01 -0.2471429
# 2: 2016-04-01 -0.5185714
# 3: 2016-03-01 -0.5085714
# 4: 2016-02-01 -0.5700000
```

If you wanted to create a new `data.table` with quantiles `1`, `1:2`, `1:3`, `1:4`, etc., one option would be:

```
library(purrr)
map_df(1:10, function(q) dat[Quantile %in% 1:q,
  list(TopN = paste0("1:", q), MeanY = mean(Y)), by = Time])
#          Time TopN       MeanY
# 1: 2016-04-01  1:1 -0.03000000
# 2: 2016-01-01  1:1 -0.58333333
# 3: 2016-03-01  1:1  0.25000000
# 4: 2016-02-01  1:1  0.10666667
# 5: 2016-01-01  1:2 -0.86200000
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's my fault! I do want the difference of Top3 minus Bottom3 in a efficient way

Comment: For the second one, using only data.table, there's `dat[CJ(Time = Time, q= 1:10, unique = TRUE), on=.(Time, Quantile <= q), mean(Y), by=.EACHI]`

Answer (score 1):

you could create categories and then calculate the mean of the categories:

```
dat[, `:=` (quant_cat = dplyr::case_when(Quantile >= 8 ~ "top",
                                         Quantile <= 3 ~ "middle",
                                         Quantile > 3 | Quantile < 8 ~ "middle"))
    ][, `:=` (MeanY = mean(Y)), by = c("Time", "quant_cat")]
```

Comment: Than you so much! That's what I want!